# Is publishing ccTLDs temporarily and then redirecting to subdirectories on the gTLD going to derive any real benefit?

Tags: seo, redirects, top-level-domains, cctld

I'm developing a website that has a generic top level domain name (gTLD). It isn't published yet. I plan to target other languages using sub-directories on that gTLD.

I own some country code top level domains (ccTLDs) for this website too which I plan to redirect to the relevant sub-directories of the gTLD. Currently there is no content on those ccTLDs, so redirecting them to sub-directories will apparently have no SEO benefit at all REFERENCE https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/51452/7116

I'm wondering if it would be worthwhile publishing the ccTLDs for a while before permanently redirecting them to the subdirectories. I imagine it would give a small performance boost in terms of SEO and index the website in the desired language. I know this would be a lot of work for possibly no real benefit, so I'm trying to assess whether this is worth doing or not.

Is publishing ccTLDs and then redirecting to subdirectories on the gTLD going to derive any real benefit? Are there any other ways to make use of the ccTLDs in this situation (other than protecting the website name)?

Comment: If I was there, then I will use ccTLD instead of sub-directory, do not think, you need to do SEO from scratch. If you interlink them properly, then It might boost in search result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No benefit I can see.

All you'd do is begin to build some value on the ccTLDs and then diminish it by redirecting the directories.

The only way this would result in a net gain in value is if, somehow, the ccTLDs attract *more* value during the time they're live than would the directories, even after losses through eventual redirection. But I can see no reason why that would be the case.

Likewise any geotargeting benefit the ccTLDs might have over the gTLD/directories is lost when redirected.